# Why do see Optimism wrap not found when building via webpack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack

I will get the error that wrap is not a function for the optimism package. This will happen when using AWS Appsync client in tandem with Webpack. The question is how to move past.

Comment: Please add detail to your question so that future readers will have better idea of what situation you solved, rather than just quoting an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm install (or yarn add) the `optimism` package and add an alias to your webpack config for optimism.

```
alias: {
  optimism: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/optimism")
},
```

This is what solved for me and wanted to share with others.

Comment: just wanted to add this to the ether to help others